SubString and IndexOf giving a puzzling result
This is the code to meant to pull the value from in front of a variable (in this case the variable is Net Total )
vIndexStart = vOutput.IndexOf(vNet) + vNet.Length
If vIndexStart < 0 Then
    Return Json("<p>There was an Error with " & vNet & "not appearing in the invoice text</p>" & vCheck)
End If
vIndexEnd = vOutput.IndexOf(" ", vIndexStart)
If vIndexEnd < 0 Then
    Return Json("<p>There was an Error with the " & vNet & " ending. We had a assumed a space</p>" & vCheck)
End If
Dim vNetString As String = vOutput.Substring(vIndexStart, vIndexEnd - vIndexStart)
SB.Append("<p>Amount Net - " & vNetString & "</p>")

...and this is part of the variable text in Word - the count up the dollar sign is 769

Running it in debug

It shows the IndexStart as 770, which is on the dollar. According to my thoughts this should end after the next space (" "), but it goes on the following one at 780.
What I am looking for is $29.00 but what I am getting is $29.00 Net - not making much sense to me!


You need to add a tag for the programming language you're using. There are dozens of languages that use method names like "IndexOf" and "Substring". Anyway, check that the space between "$29.00" and "Net" is an ASCII space character, and not, for example, a non-breaking space.

@k314159 - I leave the 'vb.net' tag off as only myself and two other people still seem to use it :-) - I don't care what language is used in the reply as I do C# and jQuery but it's hard to leave vb as it's more intuitive. I will try looking at the breaking spaces on the 'morrow as it's late, although it's odd it skipped just one. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

@k314159 - You were right. I added this vOutput = vOutput.Replace(vbLf, " ") to the string and now it works as intended. Somehow I thought they were interchangeable and IndexOf would interpret them as the same thing. If you want to add that as the answer I can mark it up. Thank you.
